# Raster clipper is giving negative coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, mbtiles, ecw

I have an ECW file that I want to clip and to convert to MBTILES. It's on ITM CRS, and when I use clipper on QGIS the output is in the same coordinates but negative! So 250000, 750000 becomes -250000,-750000

Here's the printscreen
[image]

Comment: The projwin is by default expressed in the projection of the input data which may be EPSG:2039 but MBTiles support only Web Mercator EPSG:3857. Perhaps the difference comes from re-projecting the data. Add gdalinfo of your source image and the generated MBTiles file.